# huge data with magento

Tags: magento-1.9, media, automation, aws

My client having website in magento where users comes and creates a tshirt online.  On each tshirt creation, there are 6 different images created using code and total 300 to 400 unique designs created per day so almost 24000 images per day. Currently one **hdd** with 1TB is attached with two EC2 instances.

Now the problem is, client wants option which can scale automatically as 1 TB is also one day will be full.

Is there any system or architecture which can provide auto scalable option. I don't want to use S3 bucket instead of hdd.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your against the technology of S3 which leaves you very limited options for auto scaling.

You could look into setting up a hard ware raid with hot plugable devices and then mount yor media folder into this raid setup.

Doing so you can in principle add unlimited hard drives (only limited by the physical number of bays) and it will automatically expand to include the new drive.

This i belive can be done as part of SAN and some NAS platforms.

This works assuming you are using dedicated hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly using your CDN then you will not duplicate your media. You even include your skin folder. The bottom line is that your external assets should be served from a central location and you should only duplicate the relevant code needed to execute the application.

For example: You need to make sure you core Magento is sync'd across servers but you should be syncing your media to a CDN.